# Can't create a folder with mkdir

Tags: php, windows, directory, mkdir

Environment info:
*Windows Vista
*PHP 5.2.9-2

I'm working on a project. Let's say it's name simply "project". My php files meant for user-interaction will be found at

> project/file.php

Now, I have a database behind this and some maps, which contain classes and configuration files in general. There is also a map for the users, in which I store images they might upload. For instance:

> project/files/Users/0/profilePic.jpg

The number corresponds with the user_id in the database.

My `register.php` file contains this line of code:

```
mkdir('/files/Users/'.$id)
```

The `$id` variable is the biggest id number in the database, plus 1.

But it won't work. I checked the folders, I have both read and write permissions(I am admin on my machine).

What am I doing wrong?

Note: the right to tell me there's a better way to organize this reserved to those who can give me a helpful answer. :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about this?

```
mkdir('c:/files/Users/'.$id)
```

Comment: Well, it did the trick, but the question remains: why did the previous code not work?

Comment: Hey, in windows you have to specify the drive letter, the system won't make any assumptions.

Comment: quite obvious why it didnt work, since the path "/files/Users/" does not exists in php+windows. The starting slash indicates an absolute path, which doesnt exists on windows.
If you want the relative path, just drop the first slash.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of possibilities:

1. Lose the first / since that gives an absolute path and you're looking to make a relative path -- so mkdir('files/Users/'.$id)
2. Does files/Users already exist (i.e., is there already user 0, user 1, etc.)?  If not, you'll need to make them first or do mkdir('files/Users/'.$id, 077, true) to recursively create the directories.

Comment: 'files/Users' already exists. All the users already exist(using phpMyAdmin for database management)

Comment: relative path versus absolute, that was it.

Answer (score 1):

In windows, a path does not start with '/' but with a drive letter. Just remove the first slash (so '/files/users/' becomes 'files/users/').

Further, what Mark said.

Answer (score 0):

PHP states that it makes the best attempt at converting the / between systems.  by doing:

```
mkdir('/files/users');
```

Confused PHP into thinking it was on a *NIX system.   By setting the root to c:, it was now able to properly parse the parameter and deduce that it was a windows system

Comment: So PHP makes no attempt to detect what kind of system it's running on, but tries to guess based on the argument you pass to mkdir?

Comment: a simple answer is yes.  It already knows what OS its running on since it was complied to the system.