# not able to create directory using mkdir

Tags: php

When a customer logs in, I want to create all the folders under his id. I am doing it like this:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

$aid = $_SESSION['application_id'];

$sql = "select * from ApplicationRegister where application_id= $aid" ;
echo $sql;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  echo "<table width='65%' cellpadding='4' border='0'>";

  echo "<tr><td> <h4> Company Name:   </h4></td> <td>" . $row['CompanyName'] . "</td> </tr> ";

  echo "<tr><td> <h4> Company E-mail:   </h4></td> <td>" . $row['CompanyEmail'] . "</td> </tr>";

  echo "<tr><td> <h4> Registration Type:   </h4> </td> <td>". $row['RegistrationType'] . "</td></tr>";

  echo "<tr><td> <h4> Plan:   </h4> </td> <td>" . $row['ApplicationPlan'] . "</td></tr>";

  echo "<tr><td> <h4> Registered Date:   </h4> </td><td>" . $row['Createddate'] . "</td></tr>";

  echo "</table>";
}

$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
echo $file;

mkdir("$file/opencart/images/$application_id/products/");
mkdir("$file/localhost/opencart/images/$application_id/category/");
mkdir("$file/localhost/opencart/$application_id/application/");

echo "directory created";
?>
```

I even checked the folder permissions. Its all read and write, but folders are not getting created. Please help me figure out how to do it.

Comment: First of all, try to create the folders yourself manually and see if the logs are created properly. I would check that first.

Comment: Try setting the `mkdir chmod`. Also, what's the environment the website is running in?

Comment: Try doing `is_dir("$file/opencart/images/$application_id")`

Comment: I don't see you defining `$application_id`. I do see you defining `$aid = $_SESSION['application_id']`

Comment: Do you have access to your PHP logs?  They might be going into your web server logs such as apache or nginx: `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.  If so, check to see if PHP is throwing an error.  Also try echoing the string you are asking mkdir to utilize.  I find that sometimes my variables aren't getting set for some reason and it isn't, in fact, related to the function that appears to be failing.

Comment: you may also want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324462/cant-create-a-folder-with-mkdir?rq=1

Comment: I am doing it in locally, i mean MAMP

Comment: Boil down the question to what's important. We don't need to see you making MySQL queries or printing out tables if the issue is with `mkdir`. Isolate the problem, that way it'll also be easier for yourself to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you making sure the folders that you are putting folders in exist?  Your first mkdir for example, make sure that opencart, images, $application_id exist and if not, do a mkdir on those before you mkdir inside those.

Comment: Yes all the all the folders are exists.

Answer (score 3):

`$application_id` is not set.

`$row['application_id']` should be set with your query.

Comment: if $aid is null, then you may have an issue with your session.  does your file include session_start(); ?

Answer (score 3):

Is `$application_id` defined anywhere ?

Comment: I have corrected it. It was $aid . Thanks. but even after correcting it, it display s null :(

Answer (score 2):

Try echoing your `mkdir`s, and see what they're producing

```
mkdir("$file/opencart/images/$application_id/products/");
mkdir("$file/localhost/opencart/images/$application_id/category/");
mkdir("$file/localhost/opencart/$application_id/application/");
```

They do look inconsistent, though - the first one is missing the `localhost` that the others have, and if a lower level directory is missing (`$file/opencart/images/$application_id/`), then the subdirectories won't be created.